# Can i hide FB page followers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, followers

It says Page follower lists are public but is there a way to hide the specific names? I've been hacked and have a huge bunch of fake followers I want to get rid or hide.

Comment: [Block profiles from your Facebook Page](https://m.facebook.com/help/185897171460026)